# Wordpress hook rest_api_init not firing

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

first thing first, this is my first question here, so please correct me if needed.

I have a plugin in my wordpress app where i want to add some rest api routes, but as i figured out, `rest_api_init` is not even firing.

Here is the code that i tried:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function (){
    register_rest_route('api', '/test', array(
        'methods'   => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
        'callback'  => 'rest_api',
        'args' => array(),
        'permission_callback' => function () {
            return true;
        }
    ));
});

function rest_api(WP_REST_Request $request): WP_REST_Response
{
    return new WP_REST_Response('Howdy!!');
}
```

And as i sayd, when i go to `http://0.0.0.0:8000/wp-json/api/test` it just gives me 404.
I tried with and without `args` and `permission_callback`

I run this wp app using latest wordpress image from docker, also my wordpress version is 6.2

Here is how i tried to test if the hook is even firing:

```
var_export('before');

add_action('rest_api_init', function (){
    var_export('init');
});

var_export('after');
```

Here i only get `before` and `after` text. Some other hook like `admin_init` works.
Something tells me that is because of version 6.2 of wp that i have, but I'm sure i just missed something like always.Thanks!

Comment: There is no question in your question. What do you want us to help you with? Also, I would rather try with a different endpoint, to make sure your naming doesn't collide with anything that already exists.